# Jquery hide element issue

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, hide

I have in my page many of this

```
<div class="price">

15 Dollars <a class="showHide">Show Partecipants</a>

</div>

<div class="partecipants">

</div>
```

I want to hide the **"showHide"** element when **"Partecipants"** div is empty and I have used this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div.partecipants:empty').each(function() {  

$(this).prev('div.price').children().hide(); }); 
});
```

**This is working only in IE.Not working in Chrome and Firefox.Why?**

Should I look for the error somewhere else than is these few lines of code?

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If .partecipants is empty then showHide will be hidden. You can do it using the following.

```
$('.partecipants').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).contents().length) {
        $(this).prev('.price').hide();
    }
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/JWgHJ/1/

Comment: yep, but what if the div.partecipants contains text ?

Comment: Unfortunately, an element with an empty text node is considered "not empty". I would say this solution is better than simply removing the newline (since it works lets you format your html).

Comment: The solution is simple. Replace children() with contents(). Check http://jsfiddle.net/JWgHJ/1/

Comment: This is working perfeclty..thanks! but the error was due to the new line?

Comment: mine issue.."partecipants" div not hiding

Comment: @Hussein if you would be so kind to explain why is better replacing children with contents.. i didnt understand thanks =)

Comment: If you want to exclude white spaces check updated solution http://jsfiddle.net/JWgHJ/2/. `children()` reference only HTML elements where as `contents()` reference HTML elements and text.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of the new line ... try changing the html to

```
<div class="partecipants"></div>
```

and btw what does the word "partecipants" means ?

Comment: I think it's pigeon french for participants

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.partecipants').each(function() {  
        if ($.trim($(this).text()) === '') {
            $(this).prev('div.price').children().hide();
        };      
    });
});
```